# Calculate Ln$(i^i)$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

> Calculate Ln$(i^i)$

---

**My attempt:**

Ln$(z)$=$\ln|z|+i\arg z$

$$z=0+i^i=0+i\cdot i$$

$$|z|=\sqrt{0^2+i^2}=i\\
\arg z=\arctan(i/0)$$

$1.$  how it can be that the modulus equal to $i$?

$2.$ how can I find the argument?

Comment: Which value of $i^i$ shall be assumed?

Comment: Good lord, I thought it asked for the log of $i'$.  I need to change my glasses prescription again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $i=\cos\pi/2+i\sin\pi/2=e^{i\pi/2}$

$$i^i=e^{i\text{Ln} (i)}=e^{2n\pi i+i\cdot\pi/2 i}=e^{2n\pi i-\pi/2}$$

Ln$(i^i)=2n\pi i-\pi/2$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: I don't see that this answer deserved the downvote either!

Comment: @Deepak I think that someone downvoted with no reason

Comment: @Nehorai Thanks, although there's always a reason, even if it's pure malice or just vandalism.

Comment: Actually there is much which is mathematically unsound in this answer. To begin with, why $z^w=e^{w\text{Ln}z}$ for $z=w=i$? Is this identity valid then? Even before that, the thing to point to the OP, which is not even mentioned, is that there is no canonical definition of $z^w$ for general complex numbers $(z,w)$. Later on, the identity $i\mathrm{Ln} (i)=2n\pi i-\pi/2 $ is squarely wrong, actually, $\mathrm{Ln} (i)=i\pi/2$ hence $i\mathrm{Ln} (i)=-\pi/2$. This makes for two serious blunders on a subject known for causing confused answers and multiply addressed in details on the site.

Comment: @Deepak You might want to postpone any invocation of psychological motives for votes until after you seriously studied the *mathematical* validity of the case. Did you? Here these are rather the *upvotes* and the acceptation that need explanation.

Answer (score 2):

A "from the ground up" solution might go like this:

$$i = e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi)}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Hence $\displaystyle i^i = (e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi)})^i = e^{i\cdot i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi)} = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi i}$

So $\displaystyle \ln(i^i) = -\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi i$

If $\rm Ln(z)$ refers to the principal value (for $k=0$), then the answer is $\rm Ln(i^i) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: And why the downvote?